# Custom Payment Method not Showing in backend When Create Order

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have created a module custom payment method. All is fine except that the custom payment method is not showing in create order page.

File system.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="400" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="adminpaymentmethod" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Admin Payment Method</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                     <comment><![CDATA[Version 1.0.0]]></comment>
                </field>
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Title</label>
                </field>
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>New Order Status</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
                </field>         
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="51" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Sort Order</label>
                    <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
                </field>
                <field id="default" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                     <comment><![CDATA[Payment  method is automatically selected if existed.]]>
                    </comment>
                </field>
                <field id="model"></field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

File config.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <payment>
                <adminpaymentmethod>
                    <model>Bss\AdminPaymentMethod\Model\AdminPaymentMethod</model>
                    <enable>1</enable>
                    <order_status>pending</order_status>
                    <title>Admin Payment Method</title>
                    <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                    <default>1</default>
                </adminpaymentmethod>
            </payment>
        </default>
    </config>
```

File Model\AdminPaymentMethod.php:

```
class AdminPaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    protected $_code = 'adminpaymentmethod';

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isOffline = true;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: please share the code of `Bss\AdminPaymentMethod\Model\AdminPaymentMethod`

Comment: @AmitBera i updated my question!

Comment: @ThànhTrungTô - Do you have `payment.xml` file located in `Bss\AdminPaymentMethod\etc` folder?

Comment: @sandip i don't have it.Tks u !. I have corrected that error .replace id enable into active. it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your AdminPaymentMethod class

```
 /**
 *
 * Using internal pages for input payment data
 * Can be used in admin
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
```

Hope it helps

Thanks
Kanaka Kishore

Answer (score 0):

For those using the new Magento payment provider gateway (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html) for the custom payment method creation, in order to make your payment method available in admin order creation, you have to add `<can_use_internal>1</can_use_internal>` into your etc/config.xml inside the `<default><payment><custom_payment_method>` tag. Also, be sure to use the correct formBlockType argument inside your di.xml where you define your implementation of Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter: if you use something like
Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Checkmo you will get an error, personally I've used Magento\OfflinePayments\Block\Form\Cashondelivery and it worked.